# How do I redistribute a VB 6 application that uses Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, redistributable, crystal-reports-2010

Assuming target system has "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2008", how can I distribute a VB 6 application excutable along with report file? Just moving the executable and report file doesn't work. I want to know how to create a redistributable package. We use CR10.

Comment: VB = VB6. I am loking solution for Visual Basic6. sorry for the confusion

Comment: You almost certainly know this, but VB6 has been officially obsolete for a while now; you will find it increasingly hard to get good support/answers as usage drops lower and lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a setup program that will automatically install your application's executable file and all of its dependencies (including the Crystal Reports runtime libraries) onto your target machines.

You *could* use the [Package and Deployment Wizard](http://www.johnsmiley.com/cis18/Smiley020.pdf) provided with Visual Basic 6, but I personally wouldn't recommend it.

I'm particularly fond of **[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)**, which is a free installer with a simple, intuitive interface used by many different commercial and open-source applications. It's easy to use to install VB 6 applications, as well. See [this knowledge base article](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vb) for a listing of the DLLs you need to include as part of the VB runtime, and specific instructions on how to modify the installer script accordingly.

Comment: Cody, I accepted few answers. I am looking solution for VB. still we use it (infortunately)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in this link, you need to deploy the Crystal Reports Runtime:

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp

Comment: Yes, the redist packages are at the link above. If you use the VSI 1.1 packager Microsoft released as an alternative to the old PDW you can incorporate the CR 2008 merge module (.MSM) pretty easily. If you don't have VSI 1.1 (free download no longer available from Microsoft) you'll have to use the redist .EXE package and have your setup package run it first before installing your program.

Comment: Thank's Bob, I never found that there was a way to incorporate merge modules easily! I found the redist link and use it combined with my setup project.

Comment: For future reference: To use the merge modules you need a version of Visual Studio that supports Installer projects.  For VS 6.0, there was a free add-on called VSI 1.1, or you might coerce an early VS.Net into doing it for your VB6 programs.  Then there are alternatives like WiX, MakeMSI, InstallShield, and many others.