# crystal report vb6 files need important on customer computer

Tags: vb6

in vb6 data report and crystal report.
What files are needed (like .dll or.ocx) import to run report and crystal report on a customer computer?

Comment: Does "vb6 data report" mean something different than Crystal Reports? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the "Package and Deployment" wizard for your application and it will pack all the necessary DLL and OCX files needed to run on your customer's computer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it was implemented, but normally using Crystal reports requires installing the **redistribution package** or the Runtime.

Here [How do I redistribute a VB 6 application that uses Crystal Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792053/how-do-i-redistribute-a-vb-6-application-that-uses-crystal-reports) you will also find information that may help you.